# How to concat multiple dummy variables to dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am kind of stuck with a silly issue, can someone please help me pointing out my mistake?

So, have like 5 Categorical variables. I have created their dummies in individual data frames.

```
seasons = pd.get_dummies(bike['season'], drop_first=True) #3
weathers = pd.get_dummies(bike['weather'], drop_first=True) #3
days = pd.get_dummies(bike['weekday'], drop_first=True)# 6
months = pd.get_dummies(bike['month'], drop_first=True) # 11
years = pd.get_dummies(bike['yr'], drop_first=True) #1 

#will add 24 new columns.
```

Now, when I try to contact them into my main df.

```
bike = pd.concat([bike, seasons], axis=1)
bike = pd.concat([bike, weathers], axis=1)
bike = pd.concat([bike, months], axis=1)
bike = pd.concat([bike, days], axis=1)
bike = pd.concat([bike, years], axis=1)
bike.info()
```

I am getting a KeyError: 0 error on `bike.info()`.

Now, upon investigating, I found it is coming only if I try to concat the year df, which is originally indicating one of 2 years `2018: 0, 2019: 1` After the dummy is created this is how it looks.

```
2019
0   0
1   0
2   0
3   0
4   0
```

Please Suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Try this if you want to keep your original df and add the `get_dummies()` df to it. `pd.concat([bike, pd.get_dummies(bike,columns = ['season','weather','weekday','month','yr'],drop_first=True)],axis=1)`

Comment: @rhug123 I tried this, why is it creating dummies for all the columns, despite explicitly saying I want only those?

Comment: I am not sure, I dont think that should happen. Perhaps giving the `get_dummies()` a modified df will work. `pd.concat([bike, pd.get_dummies(bike[['season','weather','weekday','month','yr']],drop_first=True)],axis=1)` Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, do you know why are you using `drop_first=True`? Just ensuring whether this is what you want to have (removing the first level and having only `k-1` categorical levels).

If you want to keep all original data that was not processed by `get_dummies` method, you do not need to use concat function, it's enough to do `bike_with_dummies = pd.get_dummies(bike, columns=['season','weather','weekday','month','yr'], drop_first=True)`. See example 1. If you want to keep all of them, I would recommend using the code in example 2.

**Example 1**

You have for example this simple DataFrame (taken from pandas doc)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'a'], 'B': ['b', 'a', 'c'], 'C': [1, 2, 3]})
```

When you run

```
pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['C'], drop_first=True)
```

it will keep the original columns ("A" and "B") and will convert selected columns ("C" here) to dummies. Output will look like

```
   A  B  C_2  C_3
0  a  b    0    0
1  b  a    1    0
2  a  c    0    1
```

**Example 2**

If you want to keep the original columns as well ("C" from the example above) I would recommend you to do the following

```
cols_to_dummies = ["C"]  # columns that should be turned into dummies
df_with_dummies = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=cols_to_dummies, drop_first=True)
df_with_dummies_and_original = pd.concat([df[cols_to_dummies], df_with_dummies], axis=1)
```

The output will look like (note that "C" is included now)

```
   C  A  B  C_2  C_3
0  1  a  b    0    0
1  2  b  a    1    0
2  3  a  c    0    1
```

So in your case you could run this

```
cols_to_dummies = ['season','weather','weekday','month','yr']
bike_with_dummies = pd.get_dummies(bike, columns=cols_to_dummies, drop_first=True)
bike_with_dummies_and_original = pd.concat([bike[cols_to_dummies], bike_with_dummies], axis=1)
```

This approach has the advantage that you can easily change `cols_to_dummies` to update the list of columns that should be turned into dummies and you do not need to add any row.

Final comments - if you prefer better naming, you can use `prefix` and `prefix_sep` parameters or do the renaming by yourself at the end.

If this does not help you, please provide example DataFrame (content of `bike` dataframe).